# Which package required automatically installed one?

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, debian, apt

I'm using Ubuntu/Debian. There is an automatically installed package (let's call it `mypack`) I don't know why it is there. Using `apt-get autoremove` does not remove it, so there should be a manually installed package depending on it. But `apt-get remove mypack` does not show any package that would have unfulfilled dependencies. Already tried `apt-cahe rdepends mypack` without finding any manually installed package.

How to find out which package required or recommended `mypack`?

I want to be sure it is safe to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute this:

```
aptitude why mypack
```

and you'll be told

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.